# Only first row from array being added to database Java

Tags: java, arrays, database

I am trying to add an array to a database. I could get the first row into the database but it doesn't add the remaining rows.

Here is the values array string:

> [1, Ola, Hansen, Timoteivn, Sandnes , 2, Tove, Svendson, Borgvn, Stavanger , 3, Kari, Pettersen, Storgt, Stavanger]

Here is my code to add:

```
try {
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(
                "newoutfile.txt"));
        // String line;
        for (String line = br.readLine(); line != null; line = br
                .readLine()) {
            String newline = line.substring(2);
            String newline2 = newline.trim();
            String[] value = newline2.split(",");

            System.out.println("the array" + Arrays.toString(value));

            connection.createStatement().execute(
                    "insert into person10(personid,first_name,last_name,street,city)values('"
                            + value[0] + "','" + value[1] + "','"
                            + value[2] + "','" + value[3] + "','"
                            + value[4] + "')");
        }
```

I have been pulling my hair all day trying to get this to work.  Any help would be great. Thanks.

Comment: Perhaps I'm blind, but where does it increment the line that the buffered reader is looking at?

Comment: How many lines do you have? Or is it all in one line as in your sample?

Comment: hi that's what I have been trying to do but I don't know how.. any suggestions

Comment: on 1 line the sample shows the input file

Comment: Try a while loop as Arjit suggested and see if it works better

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your values array string (the input file) should look like this:

```
[1, Ola, Hansen, Timoteivn, Sandnes] 
[2, Tove, Svendson, Borgvn, Stavanger]
[3, Kari, Pettersen, Storgt, Stavanger]
```

Then the reader and while (or for) loop will handle reading each line. Stripping the leading record number, splitting the string based on the ",", and then executing the createStatement.

If your values are in the file all on a single line:

```
[1, Ola, Hansen, Timoteivn, Sandnes , 2, Tove, Svendson, Borgvn, Stavanger , 3, Kari, Pettersen, Storgt, Stavanger]
```

Then you will need more logic to split the line into 3 separate sets of data.

If you have three separate lines of data in the file as shown at top (rather than a single line of data), then this code should work.

```
try {
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader( "newoutfile.txt"));
    // String line;
    while( ( line = br.readLine() ) != null ) {
        String[] value = line.trim().split(",");

        System.out.println("the array" + Arrays.toString(value));

        connection.createStatement().execute(
                "insert into person10(personid,first_name,last_name,street,city)values('"
                        + value[0] + "','" + value[1] + "','"
                        + value[2] + "','" + value[3] + "','"
                        + value[4] + "')");
    }
```

If all the data is on a single line in the file, then something like this.

```
try {
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader( "newoutfile.txt"));
    // String line;
    while( ( line = br.readLine() ) != null ) {
        String[] value = line.trim().split(",");

        System.out.println("the array" + Arrays.toString(value));
        int rows = ( value.length / 5);
        for ( int i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
           String personid = value[ i * 5 ];
           String first_name = value[ i * 5  + 1 ];
           String last_name = value[ i * 5 + 2 ];
           String street = value[ i * 5  + 3 ];
           String city = value[ i * 5  + 4 ];
           connection.createStatement().execute(
                "insert into person10(personid,first_name,last_name,street,city)values('"
                        + personid + "','" + first_name + "','"
                        + last_name + "','" + street + "','"
                        + city + "')");
        }
    }
```

I am SURE that someone can improve on that ugly for loop, but let's call it "good enough".
Without the variables personid, first_name, last_name, street, city:
    try {
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader( "newoutfile.txt"));
        // String line;
        while( ( line = br.readLine() ) != null ) {
            String[] value = line.trim().split(",");

```
        System.out.println("the array" + Arrays.toString(value));

        connection.createStatement().execute(
                "insert into person10(personid,first_name,last_name,street,city)values('"
                        + value[0] + "','" + value[1] + "','"
                        + value[2] + "','" + value[3] + "','"
                        + value[4] + "')");
    }
```

If all the data is on a single line in the file, then something like this.

```
try {
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader( "newoutfile.txt"));
    // String line;
    while( ( line = br.readLine() ) != null ) {
        String[] value = line.trim().split(",");

        System.out.println("the array" + Arrays.toString(value));
        int rows = ( value.length / 5);
        for ( int i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
           connection.createStatement().execute(
                "insert into person10(personid,first_name,last_name,street,city)values('"
                        + value[ i * 5 ] + "','" + value[ i * 5  + 1 ] + "','"
                        + value[ i * 5 + 2 ] + "','" + value[ i * 5  + 3 ] + "','"
                        + value[ i * 5  + 4 ] + "')");
        }
    }
```

Comment: im getting this the array[Ola, Hansen, Timoteivn, Sandnes ]
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 4 it missing the 1

Comment: You're missing the 1 due to this `String newline = line.substring(2);`

Comment: I doubt it. Open up the file "newoutfile.txt" and see what is inside. Everything on one line, or separate lines of data. If separate, then we can work with this. If not, then we are in trouble.

Comment: what ive done is outside the for loop +value[0] .. to value[14] and it adds all the records to the database but tis not the right way to do i need to loop through the array i think

Comment: OK, so all the data is on the first line. Let me write a new suggestion for you.

Comment: thanks .. the data is being stored in the values array 1 need to extract that data in sets of 5 0 -4 is the first set then 5-9 second etc..

Comment: Exactly, that is what the for loop inside of the while loop will do. So when i==0, then the value 0 to 4 passed to the execute().

Comment: its been a long day i just cant get the syntax right

Comment: connection.createStatement().execute("insert into person12(personid,first_name,last_name,street,city)values('"
     + value[0] + "','" + value[1] + "','"+ value[2] + "','" + value[3] + "','"+ value[4] + "')"); I need the value numbers to go up in the loop ive tried puttin [i] in there but it puts the same value in the database in all fields

Comment: See the latest version posted: i increments from 0 to (number of fields found in the input divided by 5). value[ i * 5 ], value[ i * 5  + 1 ], value[ i * 5 + 2 ], value[ i * 5  + 3 ], value[ i * 5  + 4 ]

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/51022/discussion-between-jedison-and-nasir-shiraz)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of your `for loop` try this

```
while((line = (br.readLine())) != null) {
   System.out.println(line);
}
```

Edit (Try this):

```
String line = br.readLine(); //read the line in a string
String[] strArray = line.split("[\\d],"); //split a string with regex = integer followed by a comma

for (int i = 1; i < strArray.length; i++) { //start from 1 because zero index is empty
   String newline = strArray[i].substring(1);
   String newline2 = newline.trim();
   String[] value = newline2.split(",");
   System.out.println("the array" + Arrays.toString(value));
}
```

Comment: I originally had that code in there but that didn't work so i tried the for loop

Comment: Hi yes itried it, it still only adds 1 record like this       1 |               Ola |            Hansen |         Timoteivn |          Sandnes  |

Comment: it is at the start but when it gets to the for loop the lines have been taken out by code , and it ends up on 1 line is this br.readLine the problem ?

Comment: i have tested that code with while loop ..its working for me..separate all the lines by enter key...

Comment: i cant physically edit the file i can only edit file with code , its a text file to start of with , which has to be formatted to be entered into a database

Comment: as you can modify the text file...so i have modified the original code. try that it will work out.

Comment: thanks for that...  is the a3 meant to be strArray ?